# Android Management API Enrollment "Invalid Token": How to debug?

Tags: android-management-api

I'm trying to enroll a new device using the [quickstart colab guide](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb). I have successfully create an enterprise, a policy and an enrollment token. I can also successfully query those using the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest).

However, enrollment is not working. Whenever I am scanning the associated QR code with a device, I get an "invalid code" (invalid code; the code you have provided isn't valid) message with the option to try again or to reset the device.

How can I debug this? Is there a way to find out more about *why* it is failing?

Answer (score 1):

The token may have expired. You can actually set the duration of the token by setting the `duration` field.
 https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens#EnrollmentToken

**Sample:**

```
enrollment_token = androidmanagement.enterprises().enrollmentTokens().create(
    parent=enterprise_name,
    body={"policyName": policy_name,"duration":"864000s"}
).execute()
```

Also, you can scan the QR code to check its contents. 
It should match the content below, with your token value filled in:

```
{ 
   "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME":"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver",
   "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM":"I5YvS0O5hXY46mb01BlRjq4oJJGs2kuUcHvVkAPEXlg",
   "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION":"https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup",
   "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{ 
      "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, my main question is "How can I debug this? Is there a way to find out more about why it is failing?"

Comment: did you ever find this?